# Dynamic main activity

Tags: android, dynamic, controls

My current project consists of a main activity in which the user selects either to sign in or sign up a new account. However currently I display two controls. What I wish to acheive is using the main activity to dynamically load the EditText Controls without instantiating a new acitivity to increase user expereince. If anyone could help me out I'd be grateful.

Comment: My suggestion is to create two fragments, one for Login screen and another for Registration screen and then manage those fragments from MainActivity based on the behavior you want

Comment: Completely forgot about fragments in all honesty. Could I use the fragments to create the EditText controls for user input and display them on the exisiting activity? Or will I have to create the controls within the designer, make them invisible to the user until the fragment activates them programatically?

Comment: you can hide edit text initially and can make them visible on the same activity based on your action

Comment: I'll give it a try and see how it goes. I may refer to this question later on today incase I have problems so I won't mark the answer currently. Thank you